# Need information on Grok patterns that use non capturing group (?: )

Tags: regex, logstash-grok

I understand the concept of writing regular expressions using capturing and non-capturing groups.

Ex:

`a(b|c)` would match and capture **ab** and **ac**

`a(?:b|c)` would match **ab** and **ac** but capture **a**

But how is it useful when I make a new custom grok pattern and what it means to use non-capturing groups.

Looking at a few existing grok patterns like the one below for HOUR:

```
HOUR (?:2[0123]|[01]?[0-9])
```

Here we can match the hour format using `(2[0123]|[01]?[0-9])` as well.
What makes the grok pattern use the non-capturing expression here? Based on what parameters should I decide to use this `(?:subex)`

Comment: I don't know what language you are using, but I think that's completely wrong. `a(b|c)` usually captures `b` or `c` (depending on whether the pattern matched `ab` or `ac`), and `a(?:b|c)` captures nothing at all. The difference is one of performance; why capture something when you don't need to do?

Comment: Re "*Here we can match the hour format using `(2[0123]|[01]?[0-9])` as well*", No surprise there; capturing doesn't change what a pattern matches.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference between a pattern with a capturing group or without in Grok is whether you need to create a field or not.

The `(?:2[0123]|[01]?[0-9])` pattern contains a non-capturing group that is only used for *grouping* subpattern sequences. The `(2[0123]|[01]?[0-9])` regex contains a *numbered capturing group* that matches and captures the value (=stores in some additional buffer with ID equal to the order of the capture group in the pattern). Mind that there are also *named capture groups*, like `(?<field>2[0123]|[01]?[0-9])` that assigns the value captured to a named group.

With `named_captures_only` parameter set to *false*, `a(b|c)` regex will match `ab` or `ac` and assign a `b` or `c` to a separate field. When you use a *non-capturing group* `a(?:b|c)`, no field will ever get created, this text will only be matched.

Since [`named_captures_only` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok-named_captures_only) default value is `True`, the difference between a **numbered** capturing or non-capturing group is removed in Grok patterns. So, by default only named captures (like `a(?<myfield>b|c)`) can be used to create fields.

I think the preference is given to non-capturing groups in common Grok patterns in order not to depend on the `named_captures_only` parameter setting.

Comment: The difference between a pattern with a capturing group or without in Grok is whether you need to create a field or not. This helped answer my question and now i could implement the same in the matches.

Comment: I would also like to know the significance of named_captures_only. If I define a set of grok patterns, it would match only the ones that are defined in the pattern set?? That's what it means?.

Comment: That means only named captures will be taken, numbered ones will be ignored.